# Multiple batteries in a capacitive closed circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, batteries

In the photo I added,there is a question as you can see and its given solution. When the switch S was open, charge on each capacitor was calculated and the voltage was taken as the net voltage of the two connected batteries. But for calculating charges on the two capacitors when the switch S is closed, only the  voltage of one battery was taken for the corresponding capacitor. Why is it so. Why the effect/voltage of other battery is ignored.Either I am lacking some concept clarity or the charge must have flown through other sides( A and C) as well.
What will be the new charge on the two capacitors after closing the switch S if the charge flowing through each section (A,B and C) is considered?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Batteries work imposing a *potential difference*, rather than absolute voltage. Once you have defined your reference node (ground, i. e. zero voltage), all the absolute voltages will have to be changed in order to make the nodes satisfy the potential differences imposed by the batteries.

The equation for capacity is $q = C \cdot \Delta V$, so you have to look at the potential difference between terminals of each capacitor. In this case, $q1$ sees $30V$ and $q2$ sees $60V$ between their terminals. These are the potential differences imposed by the batteries.  But the $60 V$ battery does not impose any potential difference in the upper loop, nor the $30 V$ battery does so in the lower loop. So, the solution is OK.

Do note that in the process if closing the switch there is a lose (or increase) of energy, so you can't solve these kind of problems using conservation of energy in the capacitors.

Comment: It means in a particular loop containing capacitor(s), only that battery will impose potential difference on the capacitors (in that loop) which is involved in that particular loop which implies other battery(ies) have nothing to do with that loop, even though they are getting connection from that loop ? If yes, then why is it so ?

Comment: @SaqibRashid think what would happen if the capacitors were resistors. If you had a resistor of 2 ohms in the upper loop, the current would be 30V/2ohms. By the Kirchhoff Voltage Law, all the components that are not in the same loop won't interfere